# How can I add TypeScript typings to a snippet of jQuery code for a Bootstrap multilevel dropdown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript

I am new to Angular and working on making a multi-level dropdown in Bootstrap,  following [this](https://jsfiddle.net/chirayu45/e02t2jcc/1/) article, but it's some JavaScript code snippet there.

I am not able to write this code in TypeScript instead, could anyone please help me regarding this?

The code is as follows:

```
$(function(){
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a.trigger").on("click",function(e){
        var current=$(this).next();
        var grandparent=$(this).parent().parent();
        if($(this).hasClass('left-caret')||$(this).hasClass('right-caret'))
            $(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        grandparent.find('.left-caret').not(this).toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        grandparent.find(".sub-menu:visible").not(current).hide();
        current.toggle();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    $(".dropdown-menu > li > a:not(.trigger)").on("click",function(){
        var root=$(this).closest('.dropdown');
        root.find('.left-caret').toggleClass('right-caret left-caret');
        root.find('.sub-menu:visible').hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript so any JS *should* be backwards-compatible. However, this code is predominantly jQuery-based so it would require a complete refactor if you wanted to do this in vanilla JS/TS, which unfortunately is out of scope here. If you can attempt it yourself first, post how you get on and then people may be able to help you from there.

Comment: Agree with @ourmaninamsterdam - By the way stackoverflow is not free code conversion service. Consider doing your own [research](https://stackoverflow.com/search) or provide your effort with a code example if you are stuck at something.

Comment: Consider adding your attempts at the problem and let know what issues you have faced.

Answer (score 4):

Probably you don't actually need to *convert* your code, maybe you just need to *type* it.

Simply installing jquery:

```
npm install --save jquery
```

and jquery types:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

you should be able to *fix* your code by adding the types definitions.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using JQuery or Not is a different question.

Answer (score 0):

Using Jquery in angular might not be a good option. you should use some angular package which has components written on bootstrap such as [ngx-bootstrap](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/dropdowns#nested-dropdowns).

Jquery(**Imperative**) and Angular(**Declarative**) both follow a different approach. So it would not be a good option.